# c++ makefile append prefeix to list of double-quoted items with spaces

Tags: c++, makefile, whitespace, gnu-make

Lets say I have this in my makefile:

```
FOLDERS = "C:\Program Files\some3rdpartytool\inc\thing1.h" \
          "C:\Program Files\some3rdpartytool\lib\libthing.lib" \
          "C:\data\data1.h" \
```

Now I want INCLUDE to contain:

```
INCLUDE = -I"C:\Program Files\some3rdpartytool\inc" \
          -I"C:\Program Files\some3rdpartytool\lib" \
          -I"C:\data" \
```

Normally this is easy - you just to something like:

```
INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I, $(FOLDERS))
# you can also use the standard makefile function to take the folder path
# only - I just forget what it is off the top of my head...
```

But no matter what I do, this always only works on white space separated lists (as it is designed to) so I get something like this:

```
INCLUDE = -I"C:\Program \
          -IFiles\some3rdpartytool\inc" \
          -I"C:\Program \
          -IFiles\some3rdpartytool\lib" \
          -I"C:\data" \
```

Is there a standard makefile way to do this? (standard == portable), I want this to work on windows and Linux ideally.

**Note** I did think about replacing any ' "' --> ' -I"' but I can't seem to use a white space in the subst command... I am struggling on a way forward with this...

Comment: Which `make` program are you using? GNU Make?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using various makes from: Cygwin, mingw and Linux (gmake)... I believe they are all gmake or gmake-like...

Comment: Do no put your sources to `Program Files`

Comment: @igagis - this is just an example, its actually include paths to libs or h files which live in program files...  so your suggestion does not really work :( ... i'll update the example so its not so "stupid"  : )

Comment: @code_fodder putting libs to `Program Files` is a bad idea. Using spaces in directory names is a bad idea. There's no good solution for that AFAIK.

Comment: @igagis - You don't have to tell me that, I hate having to deal with spaces in the path ... but as I mentioned in the new example these are for **3rd party** tools - i.e. I have no choice : ( Hence the question.

Comment: Would a symbolic link to `Program Files/` solve the problem? I think a pure Make solution is possible, but it's ugly.

Comment: @Beta mm... symlink?... in windows?, in theory yes that might serve as a possibility. But I really don't think I trust win-sym-links... if it was Linux I'd be all over that (but then I would not have spaces). The reason I want to cater for spaces is to make this more generic/future proof, so even with sym-lnks I'd have to caveat future users to add them - i.e. new user checks out the project and it don't work out of the box : (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, here we go.

```
FOLDERS = "C:\Program Files\blah\thing1.h" \
          "C:\Program Files\blah\libthing.lib" \
          "C:\data\data1.h"
```

Now we use I trick I learned from @MadScientist, defining a variable that contains a space, and using a placeholder that you're confident does not occur in your paths, such as "SPACE".

```
E :=
S := $E $E

X1 := $(subst $(S),SPACE,$(FOLDERS))
# "C:\ProgramSPACEFiles\blah\thing1.h"SPACE"C:\ProgramSPACEFiles\...
```

This seems to replace *all* instances of ' ', including the ones between paths, so we'll change those back:

```
X2 := $(subst "SPACE","$(S)",$(X1))
# "C:\ProgramSPACEFiles\blah\thing1.h" "C:\ProgramSPACEFiles\...
```

Then add the "-I":

```
X3 := $(addprefix -I,$(X2))
# -I"C:\ProgramSPACEFiles\blah\thing1.h" -I"C:\ProgramSPACEFiles\...
```

Then change "SPACE" back to ' ':

```
X4 := $(subst SPACE,$(S),$(X3))
# -I"C:\Program Files\blah\thing1.h" -I"C:\Program Files...
```

Comment: That's a nice trick to double-replace replace space ... since I am hiding this rule away in a common make file (user should not edit this code) then I can probably make this into one bigger horrible rule :o  ... well done, probably worth more then a +1 :p

Answer (score 1):

@Beta's solution is nice and general.  Another option that is more specific but maybe simpler is to use something like:

```
FOLDERS = "C:\Program Files\some3rdpartytool\inc" \
          "C:\Program Files\some3rdpartytool\lib" \
          "C:\data"

INCLUDES := $(patsubst "C:%,-I"C:%,$(FOLDERS))
```

but of course this fails if you have folders outside of the C: drive.

A final option which is more general but still has a few issues (it reduces whitespace is the main one, but I've never heard of paths with multiple consecutive spaces so maybe that's OK) would be something like:

```
INCLUDES := -I$(subst " "," -I",$(strip $(FOLDERS)))
```

Comment: I did have a go at trying to replace the start string only as in `$(patsubst "%,-I"C:%,$(FOLDERS))` but I needed to specify a space before the first quote .. its possible I can use Beta's $(S) variable there?... I'll  have a play with that later : )  ... +1'd because it does also work in a limited way as you mentioned

Comment: I don't understand your patsubst... that can't work.  You don't need to match the space before the first quote IF you include enough of the beginning of the string to make it unique.  That's why I used `"C:` as my match string (in the first argument to `patsubst`) not just `"`.  If you do that it will work and you don't have to match spaces.  However as I said, it won't help if you use different drive letters.  If you have a limited number of drive letters you could write multiple substitutions.  Or you could use the second method which doesn't require that.

Comment: yeah that's why I wanted to match a space followed by a quote : )

Comment: Right.  A more comprehensive example in the question would make it clear.  The second option above (with `subst`) will work for multiple drives.

Comment: When I read *"I've never heard of paths with multiple consecutive spaces so maybe that's OK",* I felt a strange chill. I wonder why...

Comment: Well I admit I virtually never use Windows (or MacOS).  Maybe the insanity really exists... :p